# What do the parameters of BorderLayout signify?

Tags: java, user-interface, border-layout

I have been searching on the Internet for a straight answer but cannot find the specific answer I'm after. Apologies if this is basic question, I was hoping someone could help explain with an example.

Essentially, I'd like to know the difference between the two lines of code below:

```
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4,4));

JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(3,3));
```

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Best place for answers to questions like this is the documentation. Do you know where to find it?

Comment: yes I do, I've been searching through but cannot seem to find a direct answer

Comment: I don't think you do. When I say documentation, I mean the Java SE api docs, that can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html). Searching for BorderLayout, you would have found the [`BorderLayout(int hgap, int vgap)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html#BorderLayout%28int,%20int%29) constructor. Learning to read the api docs is something you _must_ learn.

Comment: Thank you peeskillet, I shall get reading. Hopefully no one else will lynch me for posting this *basic* question..

Comment: Also, if you plan on working with Swing alot, keep handy the [Official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/). You will find a lot of answers there also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter of the BorderLayout constructor is the horizontal gap, the second is the vertical gap.

Check this tutorial for more information on how to use BorderLayout : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html

You should also check the documentation for more information about BorderLayout : 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html

Answer (score 0):

This is for hgap and vgap space between components: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html#BorderLayout-int-int-